# Change the width size of columns in footer in html

Tags: html, css, wordpress, bootstrap-4

I have the following html code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="footer-top-box wow fadeInUp">
                <section id="text-6" class="widget widget_text">
                    <div class="textwidget">
                        <p>
                            <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d1630.9930663068005!2d33.3123738581399!3d35.15696659507997!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x14de1a431c0b1493%3A0x552d685f196ffa7c!2zzpnOkc6kzqHOmc6azp8gzprOlc6dzqTOoc6fICLOnyDOkc6gzp_Oo86kzp_Om86fzqMgzpvOn86lzprOkc6jIg!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1525094860862"  frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen/>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <div class="footer-top-box wow fadeInUp">
                <section id="text-22" class="widget widget_text">
                    <h4 class="widget-title">Πολιτικές</h4>
                    <div class="textwidget">
                        <p>
                            <font color="#FFFFFF">
                            </p>
                            <ol>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://apostolosloukas.org/privacy-policy/">
                                        <font color="#FFFFFF">Πολιτική Απορρήτου</font>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="https://apostolosloukas.org/cookie-policy/">
                                        <font color="#FFFFFF">Πολιτική Cookies</font>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                            </ol>
                            <p>
                            </font>
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I'm using `bootstrap.min.js ver 4.5.2`.

I need to increase the width of `section id text-6` and decrease the width of `section id text-22`.

When I'm using the following ccs code, the width of both columns changes.

```
.footer-top-box  {
    width: 120%;
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: > I need to increase the width of `section id text-6` and decrease the width of `section id text-6`. -- Looks like a typo

Comment: @NikitaSkrebets Indeed, thanks. Increase width of `section id text-6` and decrease the with of `section id text-22`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The classes `col-lg-6` imply taking 6 of 12 columns above the large breakpoint. You can simply change them according to the [Bootstrap grid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.6/layout/grid/) strategy. Here I've switched to the *small* breakpoint and added color for better demonstration.

Other tips:

- Iframes and lists shouldn't be inside paragraphs. The WordPress editor may have done that, but they can be switched to divs. [Paragraphs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) can only contain "phrasing" content.
- Paragraphs shouldn't be used for spacing. There are several here with no content. Use margin or padding instead. Bootstrap has [spacing classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/utilities/spacing/#margin-and-padding) for that.

```css
/* styles for demonstration purposes */

.row>div {
  background: pink;
}

.row>div:last-child {
  background: #bbb;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-xOolHFLEh07PJGoPkLv1IbcEPTNtaed2xpHsD9ESMhqIYd0nLMwNLD69Npy4HI+N" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-8">
      <div class="footer-top-box wow fadeInUp">
        <section id="text-6" class="widget widget_text">
          <div class="textwidget">
            <p>
              Iframe here (inappropriately inside a paragraph).
            </p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="footer-top-box wow fadeInUp">
        <section id="text-22" class="widget widget_text">
          <h4 class="widget-title">Πολιτικές</h4>
          <div class="textwidget">
            <p>
              <font color="#FFFFFF">
            </p>
            <ol>
              <li>
                <a href="https://apostolosloukas.org/privacy-policy/">
                  <font color="#FFFFFF">Πολιτική Απορρήτου</font>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="https://apostolosloukas.org/cookie-policy/">
                  <font color="#FFFFFF">Πολιτική Cookies</font>
                </a>
              </li>
            </ol>
            <p>
              </font>
            </p>
          </div>
        </section>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```